# How do I create a C++ project in Visual Studio with a bunch of source files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have around 10 files, including a main and I want to compile that into a project in Visual Studio so I can run it. How do I do this? I'm running Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Urmm, create a project? And link all the files?? What kind of files are they?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512961%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Add them to a blank project by copying the files in the newly created project directory and then in the solution explorer click the “show all files“ button, right click the files and select “include in project“

Comment: @Phorce Which type of project should I create in Visual Studio 2012? All I see is Windows 8 styled apps.

Comment: @MattBettinson If the project is command line, then, I assume that you would need to create an Empty Console Application? :Banex has given you an answer that should help

Answer (score 3):

To create a project from existing code files

1. On the **File** menu, click **New**, and then click **Project From Existing Code**.

   The **Create New Project from Existing Code Files wizard** opens.
2. Use the wizard to specify the details of the existing code files that will be added to the  project and the application that will be created when you build the project.

[Reference from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/754c3hy7.aspx)